# PHP exec function on nginx doesn't recognize system environment variables

Tags: php, gcc, nginx, environment-variables, exec

I try to use **exec** function in PHP to compile a source file with **gcc** with the following code.

```
<?php
exec("gcc -o hello hello.c 2>&1", $output, $return_value);
echo $output[0];
```

I got the following output when calling via web browser (I use nginx as a web server).

> gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory

However, if I run **gcc -o hello hello.c** on the command shell directly or call with **php my_file.php** on the shell directly, both ways compile successfully.

If I append the absolute path to gcc in my PHP code like this:

```
<?php
exec("/usr/bin/gcc -o hello hello.c 2>&1", $output, $return_value);
echo $output[0];
```

I got the following output.

> collect2: fatal error: cannot find 'ld'

So, I think the problem is my webserver (nginx) doesn't know the system path environment variable to find /usr/bin which gcc and other gcc-dependencies resides in.

How can I let PHP exec function recognize system environment variables on nginx?

OS: Ubuntu 14.04

nginx: 1.6.2

PHP 5.5.9

Answer (score 0):

I'm stuck on the same problem (exactly the same...) using nginx 1.10 and PHP 5.6 on Arch Linux.
The same PHP code was working on Apache/Debian.
When trying the Arch/Nginx server, I had the cc1 error... I replaced gcc by /usr/bin/gcc.... and I am now stuck on "collect2: fatal error: cannot find 'ld'"

The same compilation works with a shell... and ld is in /usr/bin. It just does not work when using "exec" in PHP.

### Not satisfying (but working...) solution

By running gcc -v .....(just add -v to your compilation line)  I could see :

```
...
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-D' 'exit=noexit' '-D' '_exit=noexit' ...
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/collect2 -plugin ... (<= very long line)
collect2: fatal error: cannot find 'ld'
```

Then I did :

```
cd /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/  # <- path to collect2 (see above)
ln -s /usr/bin/ld ld
```

Now ld prog is available in the same dir as collect2.
And it works.

I am now looking for a better solution... :)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `PATH` variable for PHP, as it may rely on its own environment variables and ignore the system's `PATH` variable.

For example, I have the following line at the bottom of my `.env` file:

`PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

With this, executing `gcc` (without giving the full path `/usr/bin/gcc`) works correctly.

Duplicate of [How compile GCC from php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33352948/how-compile-gcc-from-php/38690920#38690920). Thought I'd post the answer here as well, since this question received a lot more attention than the other one.