# How compile GCC from php

Tags: php, c++, gcc

I tried this function from php with :

```
exec("gcc testC.c -o runner.out 2>&1",$output,$status);
```

but when I print $output I get this error :(:

```
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory\n
```

If I run

```
exec("/usr/bin/gcc testing/pruebaC.c -o testing/frommm.out 2>&1",$output,$status);
```

I get that

```
collect2: fatal error: cannot find 'ld'\n
```

My user :

```
groups vagrant
vagrant : vagrant root adm cdrom sudo dip www-data plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

My gcc directory

```
/usr/bin$ ls -l gcc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root vagrant 7 Apr  7  2014 gcc -> gcc-4.8
```

If I run from terminal all work, I can compile and execute but from PHP I cant :(

Comment: Make sure that PHP's `$PATH` environment variable is set correctly.

Comment: how can I Check it ??

Comment: `echo $_ENV["PATH"]`

Comment: echo $PATH
**/home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what happened in the comments, but I've figured out the root of the problem and I'm answering this just to clarify for any future readers.

@zneak is right. If you try and `echo $_ENV["PATH"]` and receive nothing in response, this means that PHP is executing `gcc` and any other executables without looking for them in a `PATH` variable. As a result, it sometimes can't find any of them. @Marco interpreted as echoing the `PATH` variable in bash, and executed `echo $PATH` instead. However, these two variables are separate, and often the PHP `PATH` is unset while the bash `PATH` is.

In order to fix this issue, you'll have to define `PATH` for PHP in its environment variables. If you're unsure what to put, refer to the `PATH` variable defined in bash. For example, my current Laravel project has the line

`PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

at the bottom of it's `.env` file, and now executing just `gcc` (without giving the full path `/usr/bin/gcc`) works correctly.